# Setting the decimal places for a textbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc

I'm using Report Viewer Control (rdlc) to generate reports. One of my columns have the value
`=FormatNumber(Fields!bugetRectificatInfActualizat.Value,Parameters!nrZecimale.Value,true,false,false)`  and the result are 503.86 but i want 503,86 how i can do this

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Which is your culture settings?

Usually those characters like "," or ".", comes from your local culture settings.

Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508(v=vs.100).aspx, it might help.